# How do I use a complex criteria inside a doctrine 2 entity's repository?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, criteria, doctrine-orm

Lets say I have a table that holds information about festivals.
Each festival has a start and end date.

I want to select all the festivals that are live (that happen) on a given date.

Meaning, I want to select all the festivals that their start date is before or on a given date, and that their end date is after or on a the same given date.

So I went on to the repository class of the festival entity, and created a method to do just that.
But the criteria argument "findBy" expects is an array, which all the examples only treat as a simple criteria (e.g. "array('name' => 'billy')" will select all the rows that have the value billy in their name column), which uses only the comparison operator.

How can I use other operators such as

```
>, <, !=, IN, NOT IN, LIKE
```

and etc. ?

Comment: ... I also agree on the question. And ideally, without Raw query, nor QueryBuilder.... if that's possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a findBy method with comparative criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786937/how-to-use-a-findby-method-with-comparative-criteria)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll need to write your own query (probably using DQL) if you want something that specific. I believe the built in "findBy" methods are more for just grabbing objects quickly if you have less specific criteria. I don't know your entity names or where they are stored.  Could be something like this as a function in your Festival Repository.

```
public function findActiveFestivals($start, $end)
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('f')
        ->from('Festival', 'f')
        ->where('f.start >= :start')
        ->andWhere('f.end <= :end')
        ->setParameters(array('start' => $start, 'end' => $end));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

Comment: Just so you know - when calling $this->createQueryBuilder() from inside the repository class, you get a query builder with the table and alias already configured

Comment: that's not a real answer for a question asked

Comment: If that's impossible.  I assume it is the proper answer... rely on a QueryBuilder manipulation.

Answer (score 102):

Doctrine 2.3 added a [matching()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-criteria) method that lets you use [Criteria](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections).

The example by Jeremy Hicks may be written like this (note, this returns an ArrayCollection instead of an array).

```
public function findActiveFestivals($start, $end)
{
    $expr = Criteria::expr();
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where($expr->gte('start', $start));
    $criteria->andWhere($expr->lte('end', $end);
    return $this->matching($criteria);
}
```

Personally, I wouldn't use andWhere here, and use a few more lines to improve readability, like this:

```
public function findActiveFestivals($start, $end)
{
    $expr = Criteria::expr();
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(
      $expr->andX(
        $expr->gte('start', $start),
        $expr->lte('end', $end)
      )
    );
    return $this->matching($criteria);
}
```

Using an IN clause is very simple.

```
public function findFestivalsByIds($ids)
{
    $expr = Criteria::expr();
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where($expr->in('id', $ids));
    return $this->matching($criteria);
}
```

The Criteria class is in Doctrine's not-really-ORM-or-DBAL Common's namespace, like their ArrayCollection (which has supported Criteria longer than EntityRepository).

Its meant to be a decoupled way for non-repository code to create sophicated criteria. So it should be fine to use this class outside of the repository. QueryBuilder [supports Criteria](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2667) recently as well. So even when building more sophisticated queries that require QueryBuilder, you can use Criteria to give the non-database code flexibility in what it requests.

Comment: In doctrine/orm 2.5, EntityRepository::matching will return LazyCriteriaCollection to allow doing a count without fetching all rows (https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/882)

Comment: Could someone explain why `Criteria::create()` used instead of `new Criteria()`?

Comment: Because `create` calls `return new static()`, that is PHP [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Answer (score 11):

thats not the answer for Doron question
doctrine have entity repository that not make us using query at all...

```
$this->em->getRepository($this->entity)->findBy(array $criteria);
```

but what did he asked is how to complex operator in array $criteria
normal format of array `$criteria` is `array('field'=> $value);`

Answer (score 10):

I have had the same problem a while back, where my Doctrine repositories became very ugly due to complex queries. I also had to convert Yii ActiveRecord (with Criteria objects) to Doctrine, and Doctrine did not have Criteria objects at the time.

I found a [blogpost by Benjamin Eberlei](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/03/04/doctrine_repositories.html) which has an interesting solution to this problem based on the [specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).

It gives you the ability to defer the manipulation of the Query Builder object to other classes.

```
$spec = new AndX(
    new Equals('ended', 0),
    new OrX(
        new LowerThan('endDate', new \DateTime()),
        new AndX(
            new IsNull('endDate'),
            new LowerThan('startDate', new \DateTime('-4weeks'))
        )
    )
);

return $this->em->getRepository('Advertisement')->match($spec)->execute()
```

Furthermore you can compose 2 or more classes together, which creates nice reusable building blocks:

```
public function myQuery(User $user)
{
    $spec = new AndX(
        new ExpiredAds(),
        new AdsByUser($user)
    );

    return $this->em->getRepository('Advertisement')->match($spec)->execute();
}
```

In this case ExpiredAds() and AdsByUser() contain a structure like in the first code example.

If you think that solution would work for you, let me suggest two libraries which you can install through composer:

- [Happyr\Doctrine-Specification](https://github.com/Happyr/Doctrine-Specification)
- [RikBruil\Doctrine-Specification](https://github.com/rikbruil/Doctrine-Specification) (disclaimer: I'm the author of this one)