# How to use a findBy method with comparative criteria

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'd need to use a "magic finder" findBy method using comparative criteria (not only exact criteria). In other words, I need to do something like this:

```
$result = $purchases_repository->findBy(array("prize" => ">200"));
```

so that I'd get all purchases where the prize is above 200.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is an example using the [Expr() Class](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class) - I needed this too some days ago and it took me some time to find out what is the exact syntax and way of usage:

```
/**
 * fetches Products that are more expansive than the given price
 * 
 * @param int $price
 * @return array
 */
public function findProductsExpensiveThan($price)
{
  $em = $this->getEntityManager();
  $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

  $q  = $qb->select(array('p'))
           ->from('YourProductBundle:Product', 'p')
           ->where(
             $qb->expr()->gt('p.price', $price)
           )
           ->orderBy('p.price', 'DESC')
           ->getQuery();

  return $q->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Avoid using DQL if not strictly needed, it's just making your logic more and more coupled to the ORM.

Comment: @Sliq this is a doctrine behaviour and doesn't necessarily have anything to do with symfony.

Comment: @Sliq after you try some more frameworks, you'll realize that Symfony isn't so crappy

Comment: If I see correctly, this function is a repository method. Here, you can go straight to `$this->createQueryBuilder('p')` instead of going around, via *EntityManager*: `$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()`.

Comment: @Ocramius Can you expand on this please? (not using DQL -- isn't that the core of doctrine?)

Answer (score 229):

The class [`Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php) implements [`Doctrine\Common\Collections\Selectable`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/v1.0/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Selectable.php) API.

The `Selectable` interface is very flexible and quite new, but it will allow you to handle comparisons and more complex criteria easily on both repositories and single collections of items, regardless if in ORM or ODM or completely separate problems.

This would be a comparison criteria as you just requested as in Doctrine ORM `2.3.2`:

```
$criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
$criteria->where(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::expr()->gt('prize', 200));

$result = $entityRepository->matching($criteria);
```

The major advantage in this API is that you are implementing some sort of strategy pattern here, and it works with repositories, collections, lazy collections and everywhere the `Selectable` API is implemented.

This allows you to get rid of dozens of special methods you wrote for your repositories (like `findOneBySomethingWithParticularRule`), and instead focus on writing your own criteria classes, each representing one of these particular filters.

Comment: Note: I'm using symfony 2.8.11 with doctrine and - maybe just there - it's "Criteria::expr()->gt()", not "$criteria->expr()->gt()".

Comment: It's a static method: https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/2dfc898f2a66c192d6a195bdc9c5040f65adfaab/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Criteria.php#L83

Also: Symfony is *NOT* Doctrine. Reference doctrine stuff with doctrine names and versioning :-P

Comment: @Ocramius then it should be `$criteria::expr()->gt()` ideally, no?

Comment: `Criteria::expr()` also OK - feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: I do get an error here. I try to loop over `$result` in a twig template and only get `Unrecognized field: 0` pointing to the line `{% for r in result %}`.

Comment: Having concrete repository methods like `findOneBySomethingWithParticularRule` is a good thing IMO as it decouples your business logic from Doctrine implementation details like the criteria builder.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use either [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) or the [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). E.g. in your Purchase-[EntityRepository](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories) you could do something like this:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
          ->where('p.prize > :purchasePrize')
          ->setParameter('purchasePrize', 200)
          ->getQuery();

$q->getResult();
```

For even more complex scenarios take a look at the [Expr() class](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class).

Comment: Avoid using DQL where not strictly necessary. It locks you into the ORM specific API, and is not really re-usable. There are some cases where DQL is required, but this is not one of those.

Comment: how does using the QueryBuilder not lock you into doctrine in exactly the same way?

Answer (score 6):

```
$criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
    $criteria->where($criteria->expr()->gt('id', 'id'))
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->orderBy(array("id" => $criteria::DESC));

$results = $articlesRepo->matching($criteria);
```

Comment: This is not working for me, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450970/get-elements-from-lazyloadcollection

Answer (score 4):

The Symfony documentation now explicitly shows how to do this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT p
    FROM AppBundle:Product p
    WHERE p.price > :price
    ORDER BY p.price ASC'
)->setParameter('price', '19.99');    
$products = $query->getResult();
```

From http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql

Answer (score 2):

I like to use such static methods:

```php
$result = $purchases_repository->matching(
    Criteria::create()->where(
        Criteria::expr()->gt('prize', 200)
    )
);
```

Of course, you can push logic when it is 1 condition, but when you have more conditions it is better to divide it into fragments, configure and pass it to the method:

```php
$expr = Criteria::expr();

$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->where($expr->gt('prize', 200));
$criteria->orderBy(['prize' => Criteria::DESC]);

$result = $purchases_repository->matching($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying the findBy query and modifying it to return your expected result is a good approach.