# Symfony Entity - Order joined Entities in a ManyToMany join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

So let's say we use a `User` and a `Ticket` class. They are normal entities, nothing fancy.

The User class contains this lines:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ticket", mappedBy="collaborateurs")
 **/
private $tickets;
```

The Ticket class contains this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="tickets")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_to_tickets")
 **/
private $collaborateurs;
```

To get all ticket's a user has I can just call the `getTickets()` function created by Symfony. As far as good. The `Ticket` class has a few additional fields like `updated` which is a `DateTime` field or `status` which is an integer. I would like to sort those tickets by `status DESC` and `updated DESC`

I know I could just make a function in the repository like `findTicketsByUserOrderedByFooBar($user)`, but I'm wondering if there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an Helper method to your User entity and sort/filter DIRECTLY on the `ArrayCollection` with [doctrine2 criteria](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections). Something like this:

```
/**
* this return a ArrayCollection
*/
public function getTicketsByUserOrderedByFooBar()
{
            $criteria = Criteria::create()
                        ->orderBy(array('foo'=>'DESC','bar' =>'ASC'))

        return $this->tickets->matching($criteria);

}


/**
* this return a ArrayCollection
*/
public function getTicketsByUserOrderedBytitle()
{
            $criteria = Criteria::create()
                        ->orderBy(array('title'=>'DESC'))

        return $this->tickets->matching($criteria);

}
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023739/trying-to-understand-doctrine-criteria-and-if-caching-is-possible/28024023#28024023)

Hope this help.

Comment: On recommendation would be to use a private base method like `private function getTicketsOrderedBy(array $orderBy = array()) { if (empty($orderBy)) { return $this->tickets; } $criteria = ...; return $this->tickets->matching($criteria); }` and then call that from the helper methods like `return $this->getTicketsOrderedBy(array('foo' => 'DESC', 'bar' => 'ASC'))`. This way you could get rid off possible a whole bunch of repeated code.

Comment: Also, the `ByUser` in the method name is redundant because the tickets are already associated with the `User` object.

Comment: Nice one! I think, I'll use that. Btw. Is there a way to use caching on those mapping? With a normal query I could do it with Doctrine: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html is it right, that I need to implement an own caching here in the `getTicketsOrderedBy(...)` function or can I do this directly with the criteria?

Comment: Hi @wawa i don't know how to cache at this level. I usually use doctrine cache on the entity_manager level specify it as attribute in the `config.yml` at level of `orm\entity_managers\<name>\<type>_cache_driver` . Hope this help

Comment: Looks good, but what if there is a huge portion of data and/or compex keys? Sorting on php-side not SQL will have a negative impact on runtime perfomance.

Answer (score 7):

If you always want your tickets to be in that order you can set and `orderBy` on the association.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ticket", mappedBy="collaborateurs")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"status" = "DESC", "updated" = "DESC"})
 **/
private $tickets;
```

Comment: This does the trick for now, but what if I need the tickets ordered differently in another place, for example alphabetically by the `title`?

Comment: @wawa - in case you need to use different ordering in different places, - use EntityRepository with custom query;

Comment: Hi @Qoop what you think about my solutions? Can be applied on the context of the questions? I want to know your personal opinion about that

Comment: I've never use that approach to be honest but it does look like it would be the easiest way of achieving the multiple sorts. The docs say that it works on the SQL as well as the PHP so it wouldn't need to looping through the whole collection to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a function the way you suggested would be the suggested approach.

Comment: Then I'll end up with a few repository classes containing different sources, calling them from the controllers and passing the data to different views, right?