# Applying conditional query to Doctrine's `getRepository()`

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to find my feet with Symfony and Doctrine and although I'm guessing it's far from elegant, I have managed to get the below working **IF** I use `findall()`. My main issue is that I'm trying to only return events which are yet to occur. Below is my attempt using `expr()->gr()`:

My controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationType;
use AppBundle\Form\Model\Registration;
use AppBundle\Entity\Events;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/events", name="events")
     */
    public function eventsAction(Request $request)
    {
        $calendar = $this->getDoctrine()
                         ->getRepository('AppBundle:Events');
        $criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
        $criteria->where($criteria->expr()->gt('EventDate',date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ));
        $list=$calendar->matching($criteria);

        return $this->render('default/events.html.twig', array(
            'title' => 'Events',
             'list' => $list,
        ));
    }
}
```

My `Events.php` entity is:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Events
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Events")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Events
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="EventDate", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $eventdate;
```

When I try to load the page I get:

> Unrecognized field: EventDate

I'm assuming it's a case-sensitive issue somewhere? I have it in my database (`EventDate`) and my `Events` entity annotation specifies `name="EventDate"`.  I've tried changing `private $eventdate` to `private $EventDate` but this gives me an even more serious looking error so I quickly retreated:

> FatalErrorException in DateType.php line 53: Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: use DateTime instead of date: `new \DateTime('now')`  instead of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: Thanks @Matteo - I'll be sure to remember that for future :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience using criteria, but this is very easy to accomplish using the Doctrine Query Language (DQL).

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$result = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT e FROM AppBundle:Events e
            WHERE e.eventdate > :date'
        )
        ->setParameter(':date', $date)
        ->getResult();
```

`$date` has to be an instance of `\DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks @LorenzSchaef - I had come across possible DQL solutions although I read the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14790069/3972769 which recommends against using DQL (and judging by upvotes I assume to be be best solution?)