# Symfony Equal to and Not Equal to Criteria on Entity

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i want to perform a Find operation on Entity Results.

```
$stores = c2gr($this, 'EducateToolsBundle:Stores')->findBy(['selectOption' => true, 'center_type_id' => 9])
```

i want to do center_type_id != 9

Comment: What is the `c2gr()` returns? (repository instance?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a DQL or `QueryBuilder`.

```
$repository
    ->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->where('s.selectOption = :selectOption')
    ->andWhere('s.center_type_id <> :center_type_id')
    ->setParameters([
        'selectOption'   => true
        'center_type_id' => 9,
    ])
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: i got the Solution with the same Strategy. if is there any other way.?

Comment: Other ways are 1) lazy/eager loading with manual traversal and filtering or 2) using a native queries. Both methods have an obvious drawbacks.  DQL/QueryBuilder or Criteria API is your choice.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to achieve that by using `Criteria` class. Something like this should work:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

$criteria = Criteria::create();

$criteria->where($criteria->expr()->neq('center_type_id', 9));
$criteria->andWhere($criteria->expr()->eq('selectOption', true));

$entityRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('C2EducateToolsBundle:Stores');

$result = $entityRepository->matching($criteria);
```

**NOTE:** above will work if you are in class which extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` since it is using `getDoctrine` method. If you are not in such class you should either inject `EntityManager` or get it from service container.

For more details you should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790069/2393077)

Comment: 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria' will come with Doctrine .? if yes can you share the file path which i have to use in contoller, if not share related doc.

Comment: yes, it is a part of Doctrine since version 2.3, check my edited answer, I added `use` statement

Comment: Can update your answer with namespace includes in the Enitity, and in controller.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria' not found

Comment: which version of doctrine are you using? Criteria class is a part of DoctrineCollections https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Criteria.php

Comment: Symfony version  : 2.0.9

Comment: symfony version is not relevant here, doctrine is, so which version of doctrine are you using? (check your composer.json file)

Comment: doctrine version ~2.1

Comment: Then we have an answer: Criteria is available from version 2.3