# Get elements from LazyLoadCollection

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I have found `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria` to be a very useful concept, if they worked for me.

In a symfony controller, I am calling this code:

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->gt('position', 0))
    ->orderBy(['riskPosition', Criteria::ASC]);
$positions= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(DataCategory::class)->matching($criteria);

dump($positions->count()); // dumps 1, correct!
dump($positions);
foreach($positions as $r)
    dump($r); // -> Unrecognized field: 0
```

`dump($positions)` gives

```
LazyCriteriaCollection {#881 ▼
  #entityPersister: JoinedSubclassPersister {#849 ▶}
  #criteria: Criteria {#848 ▼
    -expression: Comparison {#836 ▶}
    -orderings: array:2 [▶]
    -firstResult: null
    -maxResults: null
  }
  -count: 1
  #collection: null
  #initialized: false
}
```

As soon as I access an element of the returned array, I get an error

```
ORMException::unrecognizedField(0)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php (line 1193)
```

But as soon as I want to access the elements (e.g. loop and dump) I get some error like `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unrecognized field: 0").`

As far as I have studied the code, the problem is that the query results have not been fetched from the database. Only `count()` works. **How can I trigger this fetch?**

Does it matter that my entity has `@ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")`?

This code (circumventing the use of `Criteria`) does give correct results, but I'd like to use Criteria:

```
$riskPositions = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(DataCategory::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.position > 0')
    ->orderBy('p.position', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Comment: How do you loop $positions? foreach($positions as $position) or $positions[0] etc?

Comment: Yes, I loop via `foreach`, or in twig via `{# for pos in positions #} `

Comment: Can you add that code?

Comment: I added the code and error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by line:

```
->orderBy(['riskPosition', Criteria::ASC]);
```

Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria `s **orderBy** accepts an array argument where

> Keys are field and values are the order, being either ASC or DESC.

[github link](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/v1.5.0/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Criteria.php#L193)

Apparently, there is a mistake at [doctrine s documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#adding-a-criteria-to-a-query).

So doctrine thinks that "0", which is the 1st key of the array argument, is the field to sort by, but cannot find it.

To solve, change the above line to:

```
->orderBy(['riskPosition' => Criteria::ASC]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You nailed it. I will try to submit this problem to the doctrine maintainers, so that the docs can be corrected. **THANK YOU**