# How can I pass `userId != 10` in ZF2 and Doctrine?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

How can I pass `userId != 10` in ZF2 and Doctrine?

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository('Application\Entity\Usermain');
$emailexists = $repository->findBy(array(
    'userEmail' => $postData['email'],
    'userId!'   => '!'. $postData['id']
));
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349790/how-do-i-use-a-complex-criteria-inside-a-doctrine-2-entitys-repository)

Comment: Set up a mapper and use the query builder to get this kind of stuff done.  It'll really DRY up your code in the long run, and your mappers become memorable places to insert entity to domain logic like this.