# Symfony | Externalize "where" in a querybuilder

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder, symfony

I have a repository with many function like this :

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->where('q.deleted = :deleted')
            ->setParameter('deleted', false)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

But i have to use this part in many others functions :

```
->where('q.deleted = :deleted')
->setParameter('deleted', false)
```

And do something like :

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('q')
     ->checkIfDeleted()
     ...
```

Is it possible ? Sorry if it exists, I check in QueryBuilder documentation but I can't find a way to do it.

TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess **Filtering Collections** is what you're looking for. Look at this example from the [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections):

```
$group          = $entityManager->find('Group', $groupId);
$userCollection = $group->getUsers();

$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("birthday", "1982-02-17"))
    ->orderBy(array("username" => Criteria::ASC))
    ->setFirstResult(0)
    ->setMaxResults(20)
;

$birthdayUsers = $userCollection->matching($criteria);
```

I also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16105183/1405981) that will help you.

Comment: TY Stephan, Criterias are amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

Criterias are amazing, TY it does the job. In order to help others, this is how I do it :

```
$questionsArray =  $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    $questionsArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection($questionsArray); 
    // I'm force to do this because the querybuilder returns an Array and I need an ArrayCollection, criteria can be used only on collections.

    return $questionsArrayCollection->matching($this->addCriteriaQuestionNotDeleted());
```

And :

```
public function addCriteriaQuestionNotDeleted()
{
    return Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("deleted", false));
}
```

Comment: or user ->addCriteria($this->addCriteriaCommentNotDeleted()); just better